# Secure MySQL login data in a Python client program

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I have a Python client program (which will be available to a limited number of users) that fetches data from a remote MySQL-DB using the pymysql-Module.

The problem is that the login data for the DB is visible for everyone who takes a look at the code, so everyone could manipulate or delete data in the DB. Even if I would store the login data in an encrypted file, some still could edit the code and insert their own MySql queries (and again manipulate or delete data).

So how can I access the DB from my program and still SELECT, DELETE or UPDATE data in it, but make sure that no one can execute his own (evil) SQL Code (except the ones that are triggered by using the GUI)?

Comment: what's your definition of **evil** SQL Code whereas you have already allowed/granted permission to do **SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE**?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining that point: The users dont have direct access, but the program has. So if the user presses a button on the GUI, the program displays them data (from the DB) or save the users input to the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent injections just by parameterising arguments, for example:

```
"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE name=\"".name."\";"
```

Will read

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE name="AlecTeal";
```

But an be "injected" with:

```
name="\" or UserType=\"Admin"
```

Then it will read

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE name="" or UserType="Admin";
```

That's bad, you can prevent that with stuff like:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE name=?
```

and binding your variables, then the SQL server doesn't actually parse any data from the user, it sees the `?` and just reads from the parameters.

**You cannot hide the SQL statements yourself**

You can obscure them sure, but they'll be in your .pyo or .py code somewhere!

You have two options:

MySQL supports users - and this is what users are for and assume "Only fairly trustworthy people will get my program" so you can have a user like `Debbie_From_Accounts" who can select from the`Users`table, and update/delete/insert/select from`Financial` Tables say.

OR!

You can use some sort of API on the server and have like a set of PHP scripts that do the DB work and you just http get the pages.

Comment: Ok, but if I do a get request to the PHP running on the server, how to I get the data back to the Python client? (Reading the "echo"?)

Comment: Yeah, JSON and XML are two popular formats, but you can separate data by commas if you like

Comment: But if I need the user to login to my app would passing the username and password via GET be insecure? I would have to pass the username and password every time, to check (on the server) if this user is allowed to read this data, so no user (or "hacker") could read other users data or read without even being a user.

Comment: @c3ntry MYSQL traffic isn't encrypted either, use https to secure it

Comment: So the GET requests are equal secure compared to the pymysql queries? Https is too expensive so I think http must be enougth...

Comment: They're both sent as text over a network, you can't get more insecure than that.

Comment: @c3ntry may I ask why I got a tick but not an upvote?

Comment: @c3ntry reputation is this arbitrary thing that sucks if you have none, basically if you answer well or ask a good question, you get "rep"

Answer (score 0):

This happens to be one of the reasons desktop client-server architecture gave way to web architecture. Once a desktop user has access to a dbms, they don't have to use just the SQL in your application. They can do whatever their privileges allow.

In those bad old days, client-server apps only could change rows in the DBMS via stored procedures. They didn't have direct privileges to `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` rows. The users of those apps had accounts that were `GRANT`ed a limited set of privileges; they could `SELECT` rows and run procedures, and that was it. They certainly did not have any create / drop / table privilege.

(This is why a typical DBMS has such granular privilege control.)

You should restrict the privileges of the account or accounts employed by the users of your desktop app. (The same is, of course, true for web app access accounts.) Ideally, each user should have her own account. It should only grant access to the particular database your application needs.

Then, if you don't trust your users to avoid trashing your data, you can write, and test, and deploy, stored procedures to do every insert, update, or delete needed by your app.

This is a notoriously slow and bureaucratic way to get IT done; you may want to make good backups and trust your users, or switch to a web app.

If you do trust them tolerably well, then restrict them to the particular database employed by your app.